# jQuery Datapicker scaling... icons size won't change

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scaling, datapicker

I have changed the size of a jQuery Datapicker using `font-size`, but my jQuery-UI icons (prev/next) are still their original size (although when I ohver onto them, the div size is really huge). How can I make the icons fit the new size of the datapicker?

[image]

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261342/resizing-icons-in-jquery-ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next and prev icons are background images displayed as part of a sprite:

```
.ui-icon, .ui-state-focus .ui-icon 
{
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_ef8c08_256x240.png);
}
```

You would need to get a bigger sprite set or create your own next/prev icons and override the background attribute of ui-icon.