# jQuery UI resize Icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, icons

I already found this [Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261342/resizing-icons-in-jquery-ui?answertab=active#tab-top) here, and also [this](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/26308090/ThemeRoller-icon-set) statement of course, and even [the icon documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/icons/)...

but nowhere I find an explanation about how I use the different sizes...

I have the following HTML-snippet:

```
<div id="infos">
    <div id="info_outer">
        <button id="info_open" class="open_button"> </button>
    </div>  
    <div id="info_content">             
    </div>
</div>
```

the following js-skript:

```
;$(function() {
    $("#info_open")
      .button({
        text: false,
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-grip-solid-vertical"
        }
      })
      .click(function(){
        // do stuff
      });

});
```

and the following empty css:

```
.open_button{

}
```

looking rendered like this:

```
<div id="infos">
    <div id="info_outer">
        <button title="" aria-disabled="false" role="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" id="info_open"><span style="" class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-grip-solid-vertical"></span><span class="ui-button-text">   </span></button>
    </div>  
    <div id="info_content">
    </div>
</div>
```

**So what do I have to do to resize the icon?**
I allready tried resizing the `width` and `height` of the button, and the span inside...
But neither worked...

Comment: So you firstly, want to know why the icon isn't showing up? Secondly, if you want to make the icon a bigger size, the answer is you can't.

Comment: It shows up with no problem... but isn't the second side I'm linking a prove that should be possible...